# Update all rows with a one to many relationship count in the same table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, relations

I am trying to update all rows of a MYSQL table with the total amount of referred users for each user. 1 user can refer multiple users and I need to run a MYSQL query to update the invite count (total amount of users they have referred) on all rows.

Columns:

- id
- referred_by_user_id
- invite_count

This is what I came up with but it is not working (returns 0 on every row). What is the best way to accomplish this query?

```
SET @code=0;
UPDATE users
    SET invite_count =
       (SELECT count(*)
           where referred_by_user_id = @code:=@code+1);
```

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `referred_by_user_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `invite_count` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Just checked and my production server is running 10.3.31-MariaDB however I can switch it to MYSQL 8 if needed.

Comment: Updated with table schema. I am unsure what you mean by immediate or descendants. To give an example: User 1 refers noone and has an invite count of 0. Lets say user 2 refers user 3 and user 4, user 2 should then have an invite count of 2.

Comment: What he means is if User2 refers User3 and User4, and then User3 refers User5, is the invite count still 2 or would it be 3 for User2?

Answer (score 0):

> my production server is running 10.3.31-MariaDB however I can switch it to MYSQL 8 if needed. – webmaster8800

This solution is applicable for both MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.3+

```sql
UPDATE users t1
JOIN ( SELECT referred_by_user_id, COUNT(*) cnt
       FROM users t2
       GROUP BY 1 ) t3 ON t1.id = t3.referred_by_user_id
SET t1.invite_count = t3.cnt;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=beae1375004f1b0361ba31d54e3feeac